# Fetching objects of class B stored in a list inside class A with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two classes, **User** and **Notification** with following association:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private List<Notification> notifications;
}

public class Notification {
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
}
```

I'm trying to fetch list of notification which are sent before a specific time and belong to a specific user. I've tried to accomplish this with Hibernate Criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", "123"));
criteria.createAlias("notifications", "notif");
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("notif.date", calendar.getTime()));
Collection<Notification> result = criteria.list();
```

The problem is that originally i defined the criteria for class 'User' but final result is of class 'Notification' so I get a casting exception.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected result. You are running the query on the User class so, the output would be a collection of User and not notification

```
public List<Notification> getNotifications(Long id){

//Start the transaction

//do some error handling and transaction rollback
User user = session.createQuery("from User where id = :id").setParameter("id", id).uniqueParameter();

List<Notification> notifications = new ArrayList<Notification>();
for (Notification notification : user.getNotifications()){
   if (notification.getDate.before(calendar.getTime()){
       notifications.add(notification);
   }
}
//commit the transaction
//close the session
return notifications;
```

}

Or the other way of doing it would be to use Filters. You can find a tutorial on filters [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/)

Comment: Thanks, Say I want to fetch the notifications. How can I manipulate the code to achieve this?

Comment: So what you are suggesting here is to fetch the user object with HQL then get the list of notifications and filter the list against a specific date. It should work fine but what I want to do is explicitly with Criteria. Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: Well, your criteria is created on the User class so, its going to return User objects as result. Now, the restrictions you apply are going to filter the User objects and not of the Notifications. If you want to get the notifications directly you would have to query the Notification class. Its like saying 'select * from user' but you are expecting the result Notifications

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just one last issue fetching the full list of notification for each user does not seem to be reasonable, performance-wise. Is it possible to force this restrictions with HQL?

Comment: It looks more like a design issue. I would suggest you to have a bi-directional relationship between User and Notification. So, if you want to get all the pending notifications, you could do a simple select along with the filter for time on the Notification class and finally, group the result by users