# Hibernate Criteria restricting on an object that is in list inside a different class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 classes with the following association:

```
public class Entry {
    private Long id;
    private String poNumber;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

public class Comment{
    private Long id;
    private Reason reason;
}
```

I'm using Hibernate criteria to set up restrictions on a list of Entry objects:

```
 Criteria criteria = ((HibernateEntityManager) entityManager).getSession().createCriteria(Entry.class, "entry");
```

I have a search form that gives me lists of objects. For restricting on "poNumber", given `List<String> poNumbers` I do this:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("poNumber", poNumbers));
```

But I don't know what to do when, given `List<Reason> reasons`, how to restrict on reason. I am restricting on the same Criteria object (ie. of class Entry).

(Related to [Fetching objects of class B stored in a list inside class A with Hibernate Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042596/fetching-objects-of-class-b-stored-in-a-list-inside-class-a-with-hibernate-crite))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will still return objects of class Entry:

```
criteria.createAlias("comments", "comment")
.add(Restrictions.in("comment.reason", reasons));
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! Thank-you!

Comment: This returns different results :(